# Drupal 8 - Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered - Drupal Core issue for php 7.1

Tags: php, drupal

I currently have this notice in my log messages like a million times.
It seems it throws this notice every few page calls from all sorts of different pages.

This is not happening on my local or staging server, just on the live server.
No idea what the cause could be or where to start looking.

How do I start debugging this? There's no file or cause listed anywhere as far as I can see?

---

> Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in Drupal\Core\Menu\LocalTaskManager->getDefinitions() (line 187 of /data/sites/web/raloca/webroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Menu/LocalTaskManager.php) #0 /data/sites/web/raloca/webroot/core/includes/bootstrap.inc(566): _drupal_error_handler_real(8, 'A non well form...', '/data/sites/web...', 187, Array) #1 /data/sites/web/raloca/webroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Menu/LocalTaskManager.php(187): _drupal_error_handler(8, 'A non well form...', '/data/sites/web...', 187, Array) #2 /data/sites/web/raloca/webroot/core/lib/Drupal/Component/Plugin/Discovery/DiscoveryCachedTrait.php(22): Drupal\Core\Menu\LocalTaskManager->getDefinitions() #3 /data/sites/web/raloca/webroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Plugin/Factory/ContainerFactory.php(16): Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager->getDefinition('dblog.view_logs') #4 /data/sites/web/raloca/webroot/core/lib/Drupal/Component/Plugin/PluginManagerBase.php(84): Drupal\Core\Plugin\Factory\ContainerFactory->createInstance('dblog.view_logs', Array) #5 /data/sites/web/raloca/webroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Menu/LocalTaskManager.php(263): Drupal\Component\Plugin\PluginManagerBase->createInstance('dblog.view_logs') #6 /data/sites/web/raloca/webroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Menu/LocalTaskManager.php(290): Drupal\Core\Menu\LocalTaskManager->getLocalTasksForRoute('dblog.overview') #7 /data/sites/web/raloca/webroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Menu/LocalTaskManager.php(358): Drupal\Core\Menu\LocalTaskManager->getTasksBuild('dblog.overview', Object(Drupal\Core\Cache\CacheableMetadata)) #8 /data/sites/web/raloca/webroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Menu/Plugin/Block/LocalTasksBlock.php(94): Drupal\Core\Menu\LocalTaskManager->getLocalTasks('dblog.overview', 0) #9 /data/sites/web/raloca/webroot/core/modules/block/src/BlockViewBuilder.php(203): Drupal\Core\Menu\Plugin\Block\LocalTasksBlock->build() #10 [internal function]: Drupal\block\BlockViewBuilder::preRender(Array) #11 /data/sites/web/raloca/webroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Renderer.php(376): call_user_func('Drupal\block\Bl...', Array) #12 /data/sites/web/raloca/webroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Renderer.php(448): Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender(Array) #13 /data/sites/web/raloca/webroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Renderer.php(195): Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender(Array, false) #14 /data/sites/web/raloca/webroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Template/TwigExtension.php(490): Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->render(Array) #15 /data/sites/web/raloca/webroot/sites/default/files/php/twig/59d375a37438e_page.html.twig_bSBFdzJm9gjsbRg0uQYoaPOTU/jtYGppGYqxJtRfRiNI1jUxz1NwOIXrBmikWvb9-bw_Y.php(47): Drupal\Core\Template\TwigExtension->escapeFilter(Object(Drupal\Core\Template\TwigEnvironment), Array, 'html', NULL, true) #16 /data/sites/web/raloca/webroot/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(432): __TwigTemplate_f8a17f041581af9829850fd45db45c2b69d8b3a60b80408d416da5d23dbccb61->doDisplay(Array, Array) #17 /data/sites/web/raloca/webroot/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(403): Twig_Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array) #18 /data/sites/web/raloca/webroot/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(411): Twig_Template->display(Array) #19 /data/sites/web/raloca/webroot/core/themes/engines/twig/twig.engine(64): Twig_Template->render(Array) #20 /data/sites/web/raloca/webroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Theme/ThemeManager.php(384): twig_render_template('core/themes/sev...', Array) #21 /data/sites/web/raloca/webroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Renderer.php(435): Drupal\Core\Theme\ThemeManager->render('page', Array) #22 /data/sites/web/raloca/webroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Renderer.php(195): Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender(Array, false) #23 /data/sites/web/raloca/webroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Template/TwigExtension.php(490): Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->render(Array) #24 /data/sites/web/raloca/webroot/sites/default/files/php/twig/59d375a37438e_html.html.twig_gQv-GORxUVif_Pag4s-5z2NkO/nkgd5xff1TOsYoTsD98V_4aosHRAMT0pEKOfQcka8TM.php(90): Drupal\Core\Template\TwigExtension->escapeFilter(Object(Drupal\Core\Template\TwigEnvironment), Array, 'html', NULL, true) #25 /data/sites/web/raloca/webroot/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(432): __TwigTemplate_be8c7bbb9c824f2826368d7c8da984c6279779db72a67fd8056a00bb23b816f2->doDisplay(Array, Array) #26 /data/sites/web/raloca/webroot/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(403): Twig_Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array) #27 /data/sites/web/raloca/webroot/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(411): Twig_Template->display(Array) #28 /data/sites/web/raloca/webroot/core/themes/engines/twig/twig.engine(64): Twig_Template->render(Array) #29 /data/sites/web/raloca/webroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Theme/ThemeManager.php(384): twig_render_template('core/themes/cla...', Array) #30 /data/sites/web/raloca/webroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Renderer.php(435): Drupal\Core\Theme\ThemeManager->render('html', Array) #31 /data/sites/web/raloca/webroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Renderer.php(195): Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender(Array, false) #32 /data/sites/web/raloca/webroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/MainContent/HtmlRenderer.php(147): Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->render(Array) #33 /data/sites/web/raloca/webroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Renderer.php(574): Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer->Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent{closure}() #34 /data/sites/web/raloca/webroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/MainContent/HtmlRenderer.php(148): Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext(Object(Drupal\Core\Render\RenderContext), Object(Closure)) #35 /data/sites/web/raloca/webroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/EventSubscriber/MainContentViewSubscriber.php(90): Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer->renderResponse(Array, Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), Object(Drupal\Core\Routing\CurrentRouteMatch)) #36 /data/sites/web/raloca/webroot/core/lib/Drupal/Component/EventDispatcher/ContainerAwareEventDispatcher.php(111): Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\MainContentViewSubscriber->onViewRenderArray(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseForControllerResultEvent), 'kernel.view', Object(Drupal\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher)) #37 /data/sites/web/raloca/webroot/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php(149): Drupal\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.view', Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseForControllerResultEvent)) #38 /data/sites/web/raloca/webroot/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php(64): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1) #39 /data/sites/web/raloca/webroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/Session.php(57): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true) #40 /data/sites/web/raloca/webroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/KernelPreHandle.php(47): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true) #41 /data/sites/web/raloca/webroot/core/modules/page_cache/src/StackMiddleware/PageCache.php(99): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true) #42 /data/sites/web/raloca/webroot/core/modules/page_cache/src/StackMiddleware/PageCache.php(78): Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->pass(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true) #43 /data/sites/web/raloca/webroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/ReverseProxyMiddleware.php(47): Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true) #44 /data/sites/web/raloca/webroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/NegotiationMiddleware.php(50): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true) #45 /data/sites/web/raloca/webroot/vendor/stack/builder/src/Stack/StackedHttpKernel.php(23): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true) #46 /data/sites/web/raloca/webroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/DrupalKernel.php(656): Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true) #47 /data/sites/web/raloca/webroot/index.php(19): Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request)) #48 {main}.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your live server uses PHP 7.1, while dev/staging servers use some lower versions.

PHP 7.1 introduced [Warning about invalid strings in arithmetic](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/invalid_strings_in_arithmetic). And, yes, there is such "dirty" code in [`Drupal\Core\Menu\LocalTaskManager->getDefinitions()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Menu%21LocalTaskManager.php/function/LocalTaskManager%3A%3AgetDefinitions/8.4.x) on line 187 (`$definition['weight']` contains numeric string):

```
public function getDefinitions() {
  $definitions = parent::getDefinitions();
  $count = 0;
  foreach ($definitions as &$definition) {
    if (isset($definition['weight'])) {

      // Add some micro weight.
      $definition['weight'] += $count++ * 1.0E-6;
    }
  }
  return $definitions;
}
```

This is core thing, not your error.

Try to lower PHP version on live (say, to 7.0)?